# Uncompress txt.gz files

Tags: linux, command-line, compression

Trying to uncompress txt.gz files on Linux. gzip, gunzip, unzip are not recognizing the file format. The archive is guaranteed to be not corrupted.

Comment: What is the error? If it is truly not corrupted and *is* a gzip file, `gzip -d` will do it.

Comment: What does `file txt.gz` say?

Comment: $ file file.txt.gz
file.txt.gz: data

Comment: $ gzip -d file.txt.gz
gzip: file.txt.gz: not in gzip format

Comment: Either the files are already uncompressed and contain data or text in an encoding `file` doesn't recognize (try it: rename one to `file.txt` and open it in an editor), or you should talk with whoever guaranteed you they aren't corrupted.

Comment: Add the output of `hd file.txt.gz | head - 8` to your question and we will be able to answer.

Answer (score 5):

`unzip` is for `.zip` files not for `.gz`. Try first

```
file abc.txt.gz
```

This will tell you, if it is a `.gz`, `.zip`, `.bz` or any other file. You can then choose the appropriate program.

Comment: see my comments ^^^^^

Comment: Then your file seems to be arbitrary data or at least not any known compressed format.